# How Can I Manually Mock Svg's in my Tests?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I'm using a stub file to mock images in my application, which works 99% of the time for me. However, I have a component that will render different images based on input, so I want to be able to check in my unit tests that the input creates the correct output.

Basically what I'm looking to do is if the user inputs "Lion", my component will display a picture of a lion, "Tiger a tiger, etc. Using **moduleNameMapper**, it's always **test-file-stub** and I want to be able to `jest.mock('../lion.svg', ()=> 'lion.svg')` for specific tests.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#mocking-css-modules

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh huh?

Comment: the fileTransformer approach in the accepted answer is in the official docs at the above link

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to [Jest's transform](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/next/code-transformation) config setting you may do that.

*package.json*

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
  }
  ...
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

You need to explicitly provide `transform` to other extensions (especially `*.js` and `*.jsx`) otherwise you will get errors. So it should be something like:

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  "\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
   ...
}
```

As for *fileTransformer.js* it just emulates exporting file's path(you may add any transformation to strip the path or extension or whatever):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename) {
    return `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename))};`;
  }
};
```

It means

```
import svgIcon from './moon.svg';
```

will work just like

```
const svgIcon = 'moon.svg'
```

So for component containing

```
...
  <img src={svgIcon} />
```

you may write assertion like

```
expect(imgElementYouMayFind.props.src)
  .toEqual('moon.svg')
```

Comment: We are having the same issue when mocking more than one svg in a test due to `moduleNameMapper` being used. I opened an issue https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10458 for reference

Comment: Can't we render the actual svg somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Just a small addition to what @skyboyer suggest:

```
module.exports = {
  process(src, filename) {
    return `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename))}`;
  }
};
```

instead you need have it like that:

```
module.exports = {
  process(filename) {
    return `module.exports =  ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename))};`;
  }
};
```

pay attention to `;` after closing curly bracket.