# How to resolve SVG rendering error when testing component with jest and RTL?

Tags: reactjs, svg, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to run component tests with jest and RTL.
However, an error occurred when loading SVG as a component inside the component.
How can I render the component without errors??

The error I got is:

> ```
>   Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>   
>   Check the render method of `SearchHeader`.
>       at name (C:\Users\components\common\SearchHeader.tsx:20:11)  
>
>   23 |   return (
>   24 |     <Header>
> > 25 |       <SvgPosition onClick={() => router.back()}>{hasBack ? <Prev width="20" height="16" /> : null}</SvgPosition>
>      |                                                             ^
>   26 |       <Span hasBack={hasBack} hasSearch={hasSearch}>
>   27 |         {name}
>   28 |       </Span>
> ```

My SearchHeader component looks like this:

```js
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import Prev from "public/icon/prevArrow.svg";
import Search from "public/icon/search.svg";
import { Common, Pretendard, SpaceBetween } from "styles/common";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const SearchHeader = (props: Props) => {
  const { name, hasBack, hasSearch } = props;
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <Header>
      <SvgPosition onClick={() => router.back()}>{hasBack ? <Prev width="20" height="16" /> : null}</SvgPosition>
      <Span hasBack={hasBack} hasSearch={hasSearch}>
        {name}
      </Span>
      <SvgPosition>{hasSearch ? <Search /> : null}</SvgPosition>
    </Header>
  );
};
```

It seems to be an error while rendering the SVG, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: you are missing to import the SvgPosition component? I can not see it imported in the above code

Comment: That's a styled-component in emotion.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the `svg`,

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
  }
  ...
}
```

you can check in details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55216851/6127865

Comment: I've tried this and it's still the same....

Comment: you are missing to import the SvgPosition component? I can not see it imported in above  code -@김정수